# When use acedGetDist, how can I check if User input value by keyboard or by points?

Tags: autocad-plugin, objectarx

When we ask User to select distance by **`acedGetDist`** User can input value by keyboard like '4.0' , or click pair or points. 
Everything is OK, as long as User draws in scale 1:1. but when User want to draw in other scale distance given by points will be the same, but if User input value I need to recalculate it. How can I check how User input value?

First I tried to check system variable "lastpoint" but it is not updated when pick points in acedGetDist. I use ZWCAD (maybe that's why it's not updated)

Any ideas how to check how User input value?

Comment: I don't believe ZWCAD will have the same APIs as AutoCAD (not you tagged your question as "autocad-plugin" and "objectarx", both applies only to AutoCAD, not ZWCAD)

Comment: Yes, ZWCAD API is not exactly the same as AutoCAD. As ZWCAD don't have all functionality of AutoCAD, but it is very simmilar , at least at this point. Both AutoCAD API and ZWCAD API have acedGetDist , and it should work the same way. 
Do You know answer how can I handle this problem on AutoCAD? if AutoCAD solution will fail on ZWCAD, we can treat it as ZWCAD API bug, and then for sure I will remove tags.

Comment: so I made a quick test with AutoCAD API: the acedGetDist method always return the true value (not the scaled value), regardless the input method (pick point or numeric value) and regardless the scale (CANNOSCALE value)

Comment: And that is how I understand it should be. 

To know scale I don't use CANNOSCALE maybe I should but I don't ;)
In my application settings I let User to input scale and save it into drawing (XData of Dictionary) . Application is for traffic organization, default scale is 1:1000 so drawing in meters. But sometimes needs to draw in other scale like 1:500

In application I draw for example pedestrian crossing. So I ask for width by acedGetDist when User click points everythig is OK. but if write 4.0 User want 4 meters of pedestrian crossing even if scale is 1:500

Comment: oh ok, so if you keep the scale on your xData, then AutoCAD (or ZWCAD) will not know it... I would say that you can ask the user for unit (to ensure is correct) whenever your scale is not "default" (or as expected by your app logic)

Comment: Yes. but I suppose maybe there is some tricky method to find out the method of input in acedGetDist that would be enought. Without asking User for any additional input.